# BootstrapDialog, how to show "display:none" div into the dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-dialog

I have a html page with bootstrap & BootstrapDialog.

In that page I have a div like this one:

```
<div id="divtoload" style="display:none">Test</div>
```

I want to load this one into a BootstrapDialog.

I tried using

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
        message: $('<div></div>').load('index.html #divtoload')
    });
```

but it doesn't work because it's "display:none".

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just show it once it's loaded.

Seeing as it's an element that's not in the DOM, but newly created, you probably have to create a reference to that element, and the find the inserted element inside etc.

```
var element = $('<div></div>').load('index.html #divtoload', function() {
    element.find('#divtoload').show();
});

BootstrapDialog.show({
    message: element
});
```